# Why Firefox debugger displays just one line of the JS source file?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, console

I'm trying to debug my site in Firefox (47.0), but it displays just one line of the main source file, so I can't put any breakpoints etc:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXQ8V.png)
Other files are displayed in full. And Chrome/IE display the same source file properly.

Comment: This happens quite often to me too. Looks like a bug. Have you logged it as a bug yet? Or figured it out?

Comment: I've reported this bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1325752